# High usage of cpu and ram with while loop

Tags: raspbian, gpio, script, cpu

I am trying to use switch for executing a script(Let say script_a). For that i wrote a if condition in another script(Let say script_b). script_b is always running when rPi is on. While input of gpio is 1, script_a must be executed else script_b must be repeated. 
Here is my code:

script_b:

```
    if [ "$(gpio -g read 18)" = "1" ]
then
./script_a.sh&
else

sleep 0.1
./script_b.sh
fi
```

script_a:

```
if [ "$(gpio -g read 18)" = "0" ]
then

./script_b.sh&

else

sleep 0.1
./script_a.sh

fi
```

It works, however cpu usage is very high while gpio 18 is 0 in other words while script_b is repeating itself. How can i reduce cpu usage?

note that: i am not an expert with coding.
Thank You

Edit:

So i decided to use if condition in while loop using only one script. I am trying to execute some processes while gpio 18 is 1 else do nothing. And i want to run that while loop infinitely.
Here is my new code:

```
while [ "$(gpio -g read 18)" = "0" ]
do
sleep 0.1
done

while [ "$(gpio -g read 18)" = "1"  ]
do
#some processes are here
done
```

however it is exit while loop if i change switch 1 to 0.

Edit 2:

I added these lines at the and of the second while loop like that:

```
while [ "$(gpio -g read 18)" = "1"  ]
    do
    #some processes are here
if [ "$(gpio -g read 18)" = "0" ]
then
nohup ./stt.sh
exit 0
fi

done
```

And it is worked. But still cpu usage very high also there is only 20 mb free ram while this script is working. I am still open for suggestions. Are there anyway to reduce cpu and ram usage while doing my intended process.(By the way i am using `htop` for viewing cpu usage and `free -h -s 1` for ram usage.)

Comment: script_b is repeating itself and it constantly reloads itself. Try a simple `if..then..else` inside a while loop, instead of reloading the script in every loop

Comment: i used while loop however it is ending when switch turn 0 from 1

Answer (score 1):

It's strongly implied you are using some kind of loop that's not shown, otherwise these would just run once and exit.

If so, this fork is an issue:

```
./script_b.sh&
```

`&` puts script_b into the background without waiting. You run script_a and it hits this point because gpio 18 is 0.  So it forks an execution of script_b and then, *with no delay at all*, does the same thing over and over as long as gpio 18 is 0.

That is not far from being a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

Again, presuming a loop, you probably want to `./script_b.sh & exit 0` so that one script actually stops when it launches the other one.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it is not changed the cpu usage. so i changed my approach, you can find edit in question.